# Why isn't the submit button included in the post when submitting a form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

When a form is submitted with a button click or by pressing enter, the submit button is included in the posted fields. However if the form is submitted with jquery(`$('#some_form').submit();`), the submit button isn't included. If a click event is triggered on the button, it's included in the posted fields.
Is this behavior normal? Is there a way to include the button in the submitted fields by using the submit method?

**EDIT: ** As @Pointy stated in the comments:

> An "Enter" from an input field can cause a submit; the rules for that are somewhat complicated. Usually it has to do with how many input fields there are (like, just one, or more than one).

So apparently not every time when enter is pressed the form is submitted, but I couldn't find any info about it. Could someone post a link, or explain these rules about what triggers the form submission and which form fields are included?

Comment: That's expected behavior. A submit button is only included in the POST (or GET) if interaction with that button is what caused the form to be submitted.

Comment: `Is there a way to include the button in the submitted fields?` as you said you can trigger the click.

Comment: Right, trigger the "click", or just add the parameter name and value.

Comment: @Pointy "... if interaction with that button is what caused the form to be submitted" - does pressing enter count as an interaction with the button?

Comment: @undefined if the button has focus and "Enter" is pressed, that causes a "click" on the button. An "Enter" from an input field *can* cause a submit; the rules for that are somewhat complicated. Usually it has to do with how many input fields there are (like, just one, or more than one).

Comment: Maybe if you described more about your situation, somebody could provide more directly helpful advice.

Comment: @Pointy I've tried to submit a form with jquery and noticed that the submit button was not in the submitted data, when `submit()` is used, but it's there when a click is triggered on the button. So I was curious why this happens.

Comment: What I meant was an explanation of *why* having the "Submit" button be part of the form post is important.

Comment: There was a check for the button in the (inherited) code. I don't know why :). Triggering the click event on the button worked, so the question is just from curiosity.

Comment: @undefined Yes it is normal that sutmi button included. Take this scenario for example, You have whole form and you want to perform different actions based on different submit buttons. So in this case you could use different submit buttons with same name but different values. Thus, at the back-end, you can check which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6smh74s9/2/

**Javascript**

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = [];
    $(this).find(':input').each(function () {
        if (this.name) {
            data.push({ name: this.name, value: this.value });
        }
    });

    $('div').html($.param(data));
});
```

Comment: You haven't defined the `name` variable, but it's shown as "result": https://jsfiddle.net/y10vcyk5/ :)

Comment: Ah you're right. Little mistake! I've updated my answer. Does this work for you?

Comment: Although this shows a way to generate a query string that includes the submit button, it doesn't answer why it isn't included when the form is submitted with javascript.